# Aspcore 2 with Identity and REST (Basic Auth)

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an REST endpoint that I send the login info (email and password)

and then the server answer with a status 200 if the user sent the right info or status 401 if the user is not allowed into the system

The endpoint uses a basic authentication (using email and password within a POST JSON) and answering with status 200 or 401. But the question is how can I integrate this with aspcore identity (because we don't use EF and the endpoint check if the authentication is right). a sample of the body of the POST:

```json
{                           
    "user": "name@mail.com", 
    "password":"password123"
}
```

So the server will answer with status 200 if the user has permission to enter into the system or 400 if he hasn't permission.

How can use Identity and do the login with this scenario above?

Comment: Http Status code 400 actually means Bad Request in the sense, that the data that was sent was malformed. You should use 401 - Unauthorized

Comment: it is this number, just fixed the question

Comment: So what happens after that result is sent? Are you issuing a cookie / token?

Comment: @LucasSodré You cannot implement ASP.NET Core Identity without EF, unless you strip of a lot underlying data access codes. Could you elaborate more on where you get stuck?

Comment: We are implementing identity without EF (using https://github.com/taherchhabra/AspNetCoreIdentityWithoutEF), but the methods that are implemented as "FindByNameAsync" need to retrieve the user's completed information (such as password, email, etc) for identity compare with what was passed by the user. But we can not receive the user password to make these comparisons since this will be done on the REST side.

Comment: You shouldn’t have basic auth in the title ... what you are doing is not Basic Authentication ... basic authentication is where the credentials are passed within a specific HTTP header in a very simple manner ...